# How to properly cancel a ResultSet query

Tags: java, resultset

I have a long running query that can take as long as 10 minutes. In order to allow users to cancel this query I needed to find a way to interrupt the ResultSet
I have:

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
```

To test if it is cancellable, I make another thread

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    System.out.println("Closing...");
                    rs.close();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DstDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DstDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        };
        run.run();
```

When that thread does close it, I get the exception:

```
Exception Encountered: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Resultset: getMetaData
```

It does work, but I'm loathe to use an exception for something that is a part of the normal program flow.

I question if this is the right way to stop the long running query or if there is some way to cancel it I don't know of. Is this the right way to do it? Is there a better method?
Thanks!

Comment: Cancel the `Statement` with `Statement.cancel()`. If you already have the `ResultSet` you don't have a problem, but a metadata query won't take ten minutes, so the `ResultSet` you already have can't the `ResultSet` you are presently evaluating via the long-running query, so closing that `ResultSet` won't affect the long-running query.

Comment: After changing rs.close(); to rs.getStatement().cancel(); the queries continue after the 10 second mark.

Comment: So cancel isn't supported, but note, again, that `rs` is not the long-running query, it is the previous metadata query that is already complete.

Comment: If that were the case, wouldn't it not make a difference if I closed it? When I do close it, I can see the query no longer runs on the server and we get it stopped locally.